# matplotlib's 3d scaling bugged?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to work around the limitation of matplotlib that it cannot not scale the axes individually. In trying to achieve that by putting a dot on each axis. Weirdly it is telling me

```
.../matplotlib/collections.py:1003:RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  scale = np.sqrt(self._sizes) * dpi / 72.0 * self._factor
```

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from itertools import permutations

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
a = np.array(list(set(permutations((1, 0, 0), 3)) | set(permutations((-1, 0, 0), 3))))
plt.scatter(a[:, 0], a[:, 1], a[:, 2])
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to find the reason for this warning?

Comment: @MDan Unfortunately not. Did you by now?

Comment: No I haven't either. Seems like a lot of guide notebooks around the internet are reporting the same warning, so i would assume it is some kind of versioning error, but I haven't found the reason for it.

Comment: @MDan My conclusion was that matplotlib isn't really suitable for 3d graphics so I switched away from it. Only for 3d graphics though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue, and found that calling `ax.scatter(...)` worked (while `plt.scatter(...)` didn't for me either). I also had to change the creation of the axis object in the code sample you gave. Here's the code which worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from itertools import permutations

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
a = np.array(list(set(permutations((1, 0, 0), 3)) | set(permutations((-1, 0, 0), 3))))
ax.scatter(a[:, 0], a[:, 1], a[:, 2])
plt.show(block=True)
```

Note that the axis object is created with `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')`. Hope that helps!